# updating the data source while using connection pooling

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am running an application that uses a connection pooling in order to manage data fetching from the data base. For the connection pooling i am using HikariCP.

while the first application is running there is another application that updates the data base.
Does the data source that was created for the connection pooling being updated automatically as well? If not, how can i do it? should i create a new connection pool every time the database updates?

For example: 
The database had a record of a student with some grade.
A data source was created for the connection pool.
Than the grade of the student was changed.
How do i update the data source?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why would a connection *pool* need updating when the database changes?

Comment: To whoever voted to close as "unclear" - it isn't unclear at all what the OP is asking.  It's quite clear he needs help understanding what data sources actually are and how connections to databases (especially in a pooling context) actually work.  Just because the user has asked a question about something quite basic doesn't mean it's an invalid question.

Comment: thank you @daiscog.

Comment: @daiscog That may be your guess but it isn't what is written here. If the OP's question is unclear it is up to him to clarify it, not up to us to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html) clears up your confusion.

> Most applications only need a thread to have access to a JDBC
>   connection when they are actively processing a transaction, which
>   often takes only milliseconds to complete. When not processing a
>   transaction, the connection sits idle. Connection pooling enables the
>   idle connection to be used by some other thread to do useful work.
>
> In practice, when a thread needs to do work against a MySQL or other
>   database with JDBC, it requests a connection from the pool. When the
>   thread is finished using the connection, it returns it to the pool, so
>   that it can be used by any other threads.

Regardless of whether you use connection pooling or not, updates to the database by other applications will happen normally and each time you query the database you will see the fresh data. There isn't a need for you to 'update the connection pool'

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 2):

This diagram might help you understand what's actually happening:

[image: Diagram of database server architecture]

What Java refers to as a "DataSource" is an abstract concept representing the location of the data, not the data itself.  You can create multiple connections to a data source, but you will only have one single copy of that data, controlled by the database server.

If you update the data from one application, you're sending a message via the connection to the database server to change the data held in the data store.  Committed changes are immediately visible to any other application because they're all using the same database (i.e., the same physical data store).

Comment: That sheds a bit more light +1